# How to retrieve configuration from a marklogic server with Roxy

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, roxy

I'm starting to use [Roxy](https://github.com/marklogic/roxy) to configure my marklogic cluster (version 8). This tool allow me to deploy my configuration on many "clusters" and avoid to do it manually.

During my tests, I configured a cluster manually (through the web administration - port 8001). I'm wondering if it's possible to retrieve this configuration from the server to my local computer. I'd like to get it locally to use it for my futures deployment.

Thanks.

Regards,
Romain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this great write-up by Geert:  http://grtjn.blogspot.nl/2014/10/capturing-marklogic-applications-with.html

The sample mentions version 7, but Roxy works fine with Version 8 as well.

Comment: Hi David,i Tried to reinject the captured config on another environement without any success. I try to use "bootstrap" command. Any idea ? thanks !!

Comment: HI. What were the errors?  As an example - if the ports are already used, then you'd have to modify those.

Comment: There is no error, but my whole configuration caputed (users, forests, database) is not created on the new cluster using "bootstrap" command. I was hoping to have exactly the same cluster :)

Comment: Ahh... There is alot more to that. Sorry! To start with, please un-check my answer as the accepted answer. This will make sure others chime in. You can get databases/forests and app servers via port 8002, but I am not sure about the other items (I do not believe you can just export anything from the  admin database for example).  YOur final solution will likely be to have scripted everything and use multipl REST calls to the management API to accomplish what you want.  Sorry for this - like I said - unmark my answer so people can elaborate more by seeing that it is still an open issue.

Answer (score 1):

Perfect, thanks David.

The command for ML8 to get the roxy config is :

```
./ml [env] capture --full-ml-config
```

Example :

```
./ml dev capture --full-ml-config
```

Roxy will create an XML file with all remote server configuration.

Comment: Capturing config works well indeed, but as mentioned in the other answer, there are a few quirks in the exported config that prevent it from being pushed as is to another environment. I'd also recommend against doing that. The full-config contains way too much. If you accidentally wipe with such a config, you will end up with a crippled MarkLogic as the config includes internal databases, users, roles, etc. Use the capture to find what you are looking for, and copy only the useful bits over to your own ml-config.xml..